# Generator matrix of a binary cyclic code

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, coding-theory, parity

I need to find the Generator and Parity check matrix of a binary cyclic [9,2] code. If I calculated right, the Generator polynomial is x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 and the check polynomial is x^2 - x + 1. But how do I find the matrices of both of these? Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's what I have so far. How long do I keeps shifting the codewords?

```
|1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1|
|1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1|
|1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0|
|0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1|
|1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1|
|1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0|
|0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1|
```

Answer (score 2):

For a cyclic code with generator polynomial $g(x) = g_0 + g_1 x + \ldots + g_r x^r$, the generator matrix is

$$G = \begin{pmatrix}
    g_0 & g_1 & \cdots & g_r    &        &        &        &     \\
        & g_0 & g_1    & \cdots & g_r    &        &        &     \\
        &     & g_0    & g_1    & \cdots & g_r    &        &     \\
        &     &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &     \\
        &     &        &        & g_0    & g_1    & \cdots & g_r \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where blank spaces represent $0$. The generator matrix has dimensions $k \times n$, where $k$ is the dimension of the code and $n$ is the length of the code.

A couple options for finding the parity check matrix:

- If a code has generator matrix $G = \begin{pmatrix}I|A\end{pmatrix}$, it has parity check matrix $H = \begin{pmatrix}-A^T|I\end{pmatrix}$. You can use Gaussian elimination to get $G$ into the form $\begin{pmatrix}I|A\end{pmatrix}$.
- Another way to find a parity check matrix is to realize that the check polynomial of your code is the generator polynomial of the dual code, so that if $h(x) = h_0 + h_1 + \ldots + h_k$, then

  $$H = \begin{pmatrix}
          h_0 & h_1 & \cdots & h_k    &        &        &        &     \\
              & h_0 & h_1    & \cdots & h_k    &        &        &     \\
              &     & h_0    & h_1    & \cdots & h_k    &        &     \\
              &     &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &     \\
              &     &        &        & h_0    & h_1    & \cdots & h_k \\
      \end{pmatrix}.$$

You should prove for yourself that both of these methods yield a parity check matrix for the code.

Comment: ok, so k = 2 and n = 9 correct? Therefore the generator matrix would have a dimension of 18? Which would mean it has 18 rows?

Comment: Where I wrote $k \times n$, I meant "$k$ rows and $n$ columns", not multiplication. So the dimensions of the generator matrix are $2 \times 9$.

Comment: that makes more sense. So the generator matrix would be:

\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix}

Comment: That's correct.